# Customizing a button to act like a skip navigationlink

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button labeled SkiptoMainContent_btn that is situated to be the first item in the tab order on the page and when activated shifts the keyboard focus to the main content bypassing other navigation items. I have designed it with 0% opacity and hence appears invisible to users.

The goal is to have the button act like a Skip Navigation link for webpages. I want to use JavaScript to have the button appear only if it receives keyboard focus. Here is the HTML information I have found for the button.

```
<div tabindex="2499" class="cp-frameset" id="SkiptoMainContent_btn" style="left: 5px; top: 5px; width: 124px; height: 41px; display: block; visibility: visible; z-index: 9; opacity: 0; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <div class="cp-accessibility" id="SkiptoMainContent_btnaccStr">
        <p>Skip to Main Content button </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Assume I cannot use normal HTML means to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have the button appear when it receives focus, you can do it with CSS. In your specific example, since you can't edit the HTML you'll have to force the opacity with `!important` to override the inline styles.

```css
.#SkiptoMainContent_btn {
  opacity: 0!important;
}

#SkiptoMainContent_btn:focus {
  opacity: 1!important;
}
```

```html
There's a button here, I promise. Hit tab a few times...

<div tabindex="2499" class="cp-frameset" id="SkiptoMainContent_btn" style="left: 5px; top: 5px; width: 124px; height: 41px; display: block; visibility: visible; z-index: 9; opacity: 0; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <div class="cp-accessibility" id="SkiptoMainContent_btnaccStr">
        <p>Skip to Main Content button </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I associate my button Id with the class="visible-when-focused" with that last bit of code?

Comment: You don't have to use a class, you could equally use an id as the [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), for example if you change ".visible-when-focussed" in the CSS to "#idofyourbutton", it would work just the same.

Comment: #SkiptoMainContent_btn {opacity: 0;} #SkiptoMainContent_btn:focus {opacity: 1;}    Not working. Just my luck.

Comment: If you have opacity set in the `style` attribute of the <div> it'll override the value from your CSS. Try removing it from there first if you haven't already.

Comment: For complicated reasons, I can't edit the <div> in the html. I only have editing access to the .js , .css, and jquery.js at this time. Is there another way to override it?

Comment: Try using ! important after the opacity values in your CSS, for example `opacity: 0!important` and the same for the focus state too.

Comment: *:focus {outline: #FF0033 solid 3px;
}
.cp-frameset:focus {
opacity: 1 !important;
background-color: transparent !important;
}#SkiptoMainContent_btn {
  opacity: 0!important;
}

#SkiptoMainContent_btn:focus {
  opacity: 1!important;
}    Not working. Anything else you can think of?

Comment: @AgentOrange, just updated the example with style overrides for your specific example, let me know if that helps. If not we can move this to chat and see if there's something else going on that might be overriding your styling.